# LoadError: cannot load such file --rails on 'rake db:setup'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm having an issue trying to switch the database in my rails app from the out of box sqlite3 to using postgres.

I've run 'gem install pg' and switched the database.yml file to new settings. Also, I've run 'bundle install' in the directory.

Now, when I run 'rake db:setup', I'm receiving this error:

```
$ rake db:setup
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- rails
/Users/aaa/Documents/Projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/Users/aaa/Documents/Projects/sample_app/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/aaa/Documents/Projects/sample_app/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/Users/aaa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Any thoughts? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oy, had the wrong version of rails in my gemfile.

If anyone else finds this, make sure running rails -v has your intended result! I was receiving an error when trying to see my rails version, and then changing my gemfile solved the issue.

Comment: can you be a bit more descriptive so that this Q/A is useful for more people in the future?

Comment: also if you have answered your own question you can select it as "the answer"

Comment: I have to wait three days until I can select it as the answer, but I will.

Comment: I think what @RonM is getting at is compare your version by running `rails -v` in the console and then checking this version against the rails versions listed in your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` files. They should be the same. If not, try running bundle install before running the `rake db:migrate` command again.